# Anyone know of some good open source wikis for .Net?

Tags: .net, open-source, wiki

I'm trying screwturn wiki, and it's pretty good, but I would like to try a couple others.

The selection for open source wikis seem to be low in .Net, so something at a reasonable price would be ok too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [looking for open source .Net wiki/blog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/883426/looking-for-open-source-net-wiki-blog)

Comment: @greg, True, but that one is almost two years old.  It's possible new projects have come out since then.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best ASP.NET WIKI out there?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177293/what-is-the-best-asp-net-wiki-out-there)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/ejball/EdgeWiki is used extensively where I work.

Answer (score 0):

http://wikiplex.codeplex.com/ looks interesting as a way to integrate Wiki's into larger web applications